# Chern-Simons on a lattice and the framing anomaly

Tags: gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

Can someone make or refer me to the argument for why $U(1)$ Chern-Simons theory in three dimensions cannot be defined by a lattice action? (Unlike Dijkgraaf-Witten theories, which are defined on the lattice.)

Possibly related: what is the "framing anomaly"?

Comment: If one follow this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0004203v3), see formula $(6)$, the zero eigenvalues of the kernel (excluding zeroes due to translation invariance),  define a set of planes (co-dimension $1$), the consequence being that the CS action is not integrable.